# How do I display a div on button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I show .quick-links-container on button click?

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gnjNq/5/

I had display: none; set but I took it off so you can see the container.

So far I have this but its not working:

```
$('.quicklinks-button').click(function(){$('#quick-links-container').show();});
```

Comment: Try here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403615/use-jquery-to-hide-a-div-when-the-user-clicks-outside-of-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your element has that as a *class*, not an *id*, you want to show and hide so you need [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), your fiddle didn't have jQuery added.

```
$('.quicklinks-button').click(
    function () {
        $('.quick-links-container').toggle(1000);
    }
);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/VhX6V/)

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to add the jQuery library on the jsfiddel at the left panel.

Also, you were using an `id` (#) selector instead of a `class` selector (.) for `quick-links-container`.

Try this:

```
$('.quicklinks-button').click(function(){
    $('.quick-links-container').toggle();
});
```

Living example: http://jsfiddle.net/gnjNq/9/

Answer (score 0):

try this

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gnjNq/13/)

```
$('.quicklinks-button').click(function(){$('.quick-links-container').show();});

.quick-links-container{
right: 20px;
background-color: white;
height: 500px;
width: 200px;
position: absolute;
box-shadow:5px 1px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.2);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't succeed because of following reasons:

1. You didn't include the jQuery in your example file.
2. You have a class called `quick-links-container` in your HTML but in your JS you are using `#quick-links-container` which returns an ID. So that needs to be changed to '.quick-links-container'
3. You are using only `show()` on click therefore on click the div will always be set to show, instead you can use `toggle()` to toggle the visibility of the div.

So, your javascript code needs to be modified to following:

```
$('.quicklinks-button').click(function(){ $('.quick-links-container').toggle();});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GautamChadha/U5Rwg/

Answer (score 0):

```
// you must use toggle
// this is jquery 

$('#hide').click(function(){
var current = $(this).val();
$('p').toggle();

// this will toggle the value of button from show to hide and vice versa

if(current == 'hide'){                
$('#hide').val('show');
}else{
    $('#hide').val('hide');
   }

});
```